# What is the meaning of '별로 차이가 없다'

Tags: grammar

What is the meaning of '별로 차이가 없다'?

이 한국말은 영어로 설명하면 무슨 뜻입니까? 알고 싶어요.

Comment: '별로 차이가 없다’는 영어로 ‘not much difference’ 또는 'not much of a difference’로 번역할 수 있습니다. 이 표현은 두 가지 사물이나 상황이 서로 비슷하거나 같다는 것을 나타내는 표현입니다. 예를 들어, "이 두 제품은 별로 차이가 없다"라고 말할 때, "These two products don’t have much difference"라고 번역할 수 있습니다.

Answer (score 2):

As was answered in the comment, it means "(There is) not much difference" or "It is not very different".  차이 is a common noun for "difference", and 별로 is a very frequently used adverb which means "especially", "particularly", or "much / very" in a negative sentence.

Here are some examples of 별로.

- 손님 많아? = Are there many guests/customers?
- 아니, **별로 없어** = No, there **aren't very** many.

---

- 공포 영화(를) 좋아하세요? = Do you like horror movies?
- 아니요, **별로 안** 좋아해요 = Not really, I **don't particularly** like them.

---

- 이번 겨울은 **별로** 춥지 **않았다** = This winter **wasn't particularly** cold.

별 has the underlying base meaning of being different from others (i.e. 다르다), so it appears in many words sharing the sense of "special / particular" or "different / separate", as in 특별하다 (is special), 유별나다 (is very different), 별개 (a different thing/item), 구별하다 (to differentiate / tell apart), 차별하다 (to discriminate) and many others.